# Java how to re-transmit child call method to parent?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a two clases :

```
public class FlowItem {

}

public abstract class Flow extends FlowItem {
    protected LinkedList<FlowItem> items = new LinkedList<FlowItem>();

    public abstract void show(FlowItem item);
}
```

I have next implementation structure :

```
public class AuthFlow extends Flow {

    public AuthFlow() {
        items.add(new PrivacyFlow());
        items.add(new ExtendedPrivacyFlow());
        items.add(new FinalFlowItem());
    }

    public void show(FlowItem item) {
        // drawing logic
    }
}
```

`PrivacyFlow` and `ExtendedPrivacyFlow` also extended from `Flow`. `FinalFlowItem` extended from `FlowItem`.
The question is : how to use single\parent implementation of `show(...)` method?
I want to keep drawing logic in one place.

Comment: If you put your show method as a non-abstract method into the super parent object FlowItem could it work like you want ? You define once your method, and use it in all your childs

Comment: Probably you want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle . Starting with: if you "show" logic should be common, then well, implement that method in your base class. That is what base classes are for, in the end: to provide  **common** behavior to all the sub classes.

Comment: make a show  concrete method in abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You `show` method is abstract, meaning that each class inheriting from it needs to implement the method. I am assuming that you have information in your child classes relevant to rendering, and in this case you could move said information into the `Flow` class with relative ease. You can use a data encapsulation method similar to hold relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is simply change the show method in the parent class to be final, that way you prevent overriding in your subclasses.

```
public final void show(FlowItem item){
//your code here
}
```